# wildfly how to get link to a deployment

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly

I have created my first jax-rs web app and deployed it to wildfly. The project is pure jar. I deployed it via eclipse (added to server). Server deployed it without error and in wildfly's admin console/deployments I can see "timetracker-backend.jar"

If I click on it I can see all deployed jax-rs resources. So far so good.  But how to get there? Why does wildfly doesn't provide a link like tomcat does?

So what is the base URL of a deployed resource? In my case I tried

> > localhost:8080/timtracker-backend/...
> >     localhost:8080/timtracker-backend.jar/...

But all yield not found (in arquillian tests the URLs are working). Is there a safe way to know the base URL for a given deployment?

Comment: I'm guessing arquillian is set up to run your JAX-RS app as a webapp. I don't think you can simply deploy a jar. It should be in a war.

Comment: wildfly shows perfect deployment and shows under "ejb" all deploayed resources - they should be accessible in some way?

Comment: JAX-RS can't be deployed that way (as ejb). It in the specification that it needs to be deployed as a war.

Comment: so change packaging to war should do it? - i'll try...

Comment: Um, it's a bit more than just changing the packaging. Webapps have a different folder structure. Create a Maven webapp. Just to test, you could just add the jar to the webapp libraries. It should work. I'm assuming you have an `Application` subclass with `@ApplicationPath` annotation. If not, I don't think it will work this way, and you may need a bit more help to get it up and running.